# Interact with apps installed on Windows using WSL2

Tags: node.js, powershell, terminal, snowflake-cloud-data-platform, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I got my WSL2 up and running. On Windows level I installed node.js and now I want to run `npm install snowflake-sdk` from Ubuntu level. Terminal returns `-bash: /mnt/c/Program Files/nodejs/npm: /bin/sh^M: bad interpreter: No such file or directory` while PowerShell works fine.

Question is: is it possible to interact with Windows level installed applications using WSL2's terminal?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### > is it possible to interact with Windows level installed applications using WSL2's terminal?

Yes, you can run `notepad.exe` from WSL and it will open Notepad in Windows.

More documentation: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/wsl/interop#run-windows-tools-from-linux

### Solving the NPM issue

If I try running `npm -v` in WSL, I get an error about it not being able to find a file:

```
PS C:\Users\harvey> bash
harvey@harvey-w10x64-defiance:/mnt/c/Users/harvey$ npm -v
internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:968
  throw err;
  ^

Error: Cannot find module 'C:\mnt\c\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\bin\npm-cli.js'
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:965:15)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:841:27)
    at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (internal/modules/run_main.js:71:12)
    at internal/main/run_main_module.js:17:47 {
  code: 'MODULE_NOT_FOUND',
  requireStack: []
}
```

The path to the file is mostly correct but it has appended `C:\mnt` to it.

I managed to get around this by running `npm` by giving Node the path to the `npm-cli.js` file.

You can run:

```
node.exe \c\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\bin\npm-cli.js -v
```

But that runs into the same error.

I then tried this:

```
PS C:\Users\harvey> bash
harvey@harvey-w10x64-defiance:/mnt/c/Users/harvey$ cd "/mnt/c/Program Files/nodejs/node_modules/npm/bin"
harvey@harvey-w10x64-defiance:/mnt/c/Program Files/nodejs/node_modules/npm/bin$ ../../../node.exe npm-cli.js -v
6.14.6
```

From here I was finally able to get some output from the NPM CLI.

From here I can install the package but it will likely be installed in the wrong location.

I couldn't seem to get `npm` working from anywhere in the filesystem. This may be a limitation with NPM. Perhaps if you try messing with your path env vars, you can get it to work?

Comment: Interesting thing is I did same scenario with Confluent Kafka. Navigating to the directory with `/mnt/` prefix worked perfectly. I could start my kafka, `docker-compose` instruction etc. As you stated - this seems to be issue with NPM.

Comment: Currently I will stick to PS terminal as it comes to NPM. Great thanks for your help!

Answer (score 7):

Note:

- The **more typical scenario is to install Node.js and `npm` *on the Linux side***, as per [the official instructions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/nodejs/setup-on-wsl2)<sup>Thanks, [SeaDude](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/nodejs/setup-on-wsl2).</sup> If you then need to call *from Windows*, you can use
  `wsl npm ...`, but note that **cross-file-system calls are [generally discouraged in WSL2](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/wsl/compare-versions#performance-across-os-file-systems)**.

---

[harzvor's helpful answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64742430/45375) provides good background information.

**It *is* possible to make calling `npm` from a *Windows-installed* Node.js copy *from WSL2* work, though it's not obvious and a bit cumbersome** - though **you could wrap the workaround in a custom function or script**:

```sh
# From WSL2; note the required use of '.exe'
node.exe 'c:/Program Files/nodejs/node_modules/npm/bin/npm-cli.js' install snowflake-sdk
```

The above, which relies on Node.js being installed in its default location on Windows, calls `npm` *indirectly*, using essentially the same technique that the CLI entry point *on Windows*, the `npm.cmd` *batch file*, uses.

Note:

- **In order to target a *Windows* executable from WSL, you must include the filename extension *explicitly*, such as `node.exe` rather than `node`**.
- Without it, e.g. with `npm`, the Linux subsystem looks for an *extension-less* file by that name in the `$PATH` folders, which does *not* work.

  - Such a file actually *does* exist even on Windows, but it is a shebang-based script designed for *Unix*-like platforms, and basically just dead weight in a Windows installation; the Linux subsystem still tries to execute it, but fails, because it uses CRLF (`\r\n`) newlines rather than the expected LF-only (`\n`) newlines. As a result, the unexpected CR that follows `#!/bin/sh` (represented as `^M` in the error message) is considered a *part of the executable path*, so the invocation fails.<sup>[1]</sup>
  - Even fixing that problem manually (converting to LF-only newlines) doesn't help, however, *because of how the shell script constructs the full path to the `npm-cli.js` entry point*: it expresses it as an UNC path that tries to target the Windows file-system location *via the WSL file-system* - e.g.,
    `\\wsl$\Ubuntu-20.04\mnt\c\...` - which is *explicitly disallowed*.<sup>[2]</sup>
- Calling the *batch* file, `npm.cmd`, explicitly, doesn't work either - neither directly nor with `cmd.exe /c npm.cmd ...`:

  - Direct invocation of a `*.cmd` file fails obscurely - not sure if that's a bug as of Windows 10 20H2.
  - Via `cmd.exe /c` it fails too, because `cmd.exe` doesn't support UNC paths as the current directory and the WSL2-internal current directory path is invariably expressed as one (e.g., `\\wsl$\Ubuntu-20.04\home\jdoe\project\some-project`).
    `cmd.exe` defaults to the *Windows directory* in this case, so installation of packages to the current WSL directory('s project) won't work).
- **Providing the full Windows-native path to the npm CLI's main `.js` file to `node.exe`, as shown above, works as expected**, since Node.js seems to otherwise be handling UNC paths that refer to *WSL2 file-system* directories and files, such as the calling WSL2's shell current directory, properly.

---

<sup>[1] On Ubuntu 20.04, the CR in the *shebang line itself* no longer seems to be a problem, but the CRs in the remaining lines still are, so the invocation still fails, even more obscurely, which error messages such as `: not foundram Files/nodejs/npm: 3:`.</sup>

<sup>[2] The reason is that the Linux `dirname` utility is used to determine the shell script's own directory in order to determine `npm-cli.js`'s full path, and this utility by design operates from the perspective of the *Linux* file-system, which ends up expressing the script's *Windows* file-system location in this indirect, unsupported manner.</sup>